# Since macOS Mojave 10.14.6 update with Safari 12.1.2, I'm not able to login in Symfony 4.3 applications anymore

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, csrf

I've updated my MacBook to the latest Mojave 10.14.6 (18G87) version.
Since that update I'm not able to login into my Symfony 4.3 applications using Safari anymore. I always get the error message "Invalid CSRF token". With Chrome it's working.

I updated Symfony to the most recent version 4.3.3
I'm not using FOSUserBundle.
Apache is running with version 2.4.39 (homebrew)
PHP version is 7.2.20 (homebrew)

Any help is appreciated.
Regards, Markus

Comment: Have you checked your web console for JavaScript errors? I would start there. At the very least, it should be possible to introduce a workaround if this is a client-side.

Comment: I suggest that you should clear cache (from both Safari and Symfony) and try again

Comment: Thanks for you input.

There are no JavaScript errors in the console.

I already deleted all caches. Browser cache and Symfonys var folder. Checked the permission of that folders as well. It's writeable for my user.

Comment: When you send a request via the web browser, you should be able to see the details of the network call, including any parameters sent in the request. This is usually found in a network tab or some equivalent in your developer console. Please check what data is being sent in both browsers and see if the CSRF token is missing from the request in Safari.

Comment: Double checked that. Safari sends: email=c1%40bla&password=123456&_csrf_token=0-Wm8CvxUxZAJ9O6_178SBXy4OcBC6NSSJ4Hen_j3-o and Chrome sends: email=c1%40bla&password=123456&_csrf_token=Q_6gNgkUJuZBXqsvQSsEkKWwSHFVVMOsd7fV3UGYJB0
Both requests contain User/Password/Token

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same error.
Just comment out this line inside your `framework.yml` file to make it work:

```
#cookie_samesite: lax
```

The reason its not working inside Safari 12 is due to a bug inside the webkit engine.
It will be fixed in Safari 13.
Safari 12 incorrectly handles unknown SameSite values and will treat any unknown value (including None and lax) as if it was SameSite=Strict.

Bugtracker:
https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=198181

If my answer was helpful, I would appreciate if you accept this answer

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much.
I would never find that.